# How to get items into array from string with comma separated values in type script and any item has comma it will be in double quotes

Tags: regex, typescript, split

I've been struggling to get all items of below string into an array.

abc,"de,f",hi,"hello","te,st&" items into an array in Typescript.

If any string has  comma (,) or ampersand (&) in it,It will be placed in double quotes.

Tried split function but it fails as my strings can have comma as well.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this data coming from a CSV file? If so, use a proper CSV parsing library. CSV files are not as simplistic to parse as they look on the surface.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for reply.This is not in CSV.This string is the textbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx /(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"])*\"|[^,]*)/ has helped me get the required values.

**var test = '"abc,123",test,123,456,"def:get"';**

**test.split(/(\"(?:[^\"])*\"|[^,]*)/);**

Its returning the below array.

**["", ""abc,123"", ",", "test", ",", "123", ",", "456", ",", ""def:get"", ""]**

And when a particular values in side double quotes,I just trimmed them to get the actual values and have ignore empty items of array..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use a regular expression matching, can you try a different regEx that would match strings inside quotes first, then strings outside quotes, something like `(\".+?\")|(^[^\"]+,)|(,[^\"]+,)`

I don't know how relevant it would be in case of TypeScript, but I am guessing you'd be able to work something out that takes this Pattern and gives you the matches one by one

Comment: Tried this one.but no luck.

Comment: How did you try? The way this one will work is some logic that will give you the matches one by one, like it works in Java. A quick search shows me that the `split()` method should have worked for you. Look at this page: https://jsfiddle.net/mtzfhmvw/

Comment: Hi,For string  'abc,"de,f",hi,"hello","te,st&"' I'm getting [ "", undefined, "abc,", undefined, "", ""de,f"", undefined, undefined, "", undefined, undefined, ",hi,", "", ""hello"", undefined, undefined, ",", ""te,st&"", undefined, undefined, "" ] .Even if you ignore undefined and empty .It's picking up the array items wrongly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you are making the things more complicated than what they are by implementing the following logic:

*has comma (,) or ampersand (&) in it,It will be placed in double quotes.*

Instead of doing this that way, you should **systematically** put your elements inside double quote:

```
abc,"de,f",hi,"hello","te,st&"
```

→

```
"abc","de,f","hi","hello","te,st&"
```

you will have then the following string to parse.
A regex like this one will do the job:

```
(?<=,")([^"]*)(?=",)|(?<=")([^"]*)(?=",)|(?<=")([^"]*)(?="$)
```

using back references `$1$2$3`, you can extract your elements.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.

Answer (score -3):

**use the split  a  string .....**

```
let fullName = "First,Last"
let fullNameArr = fullName.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)

fullNameArr[0] // First
fullNameArr[1] // Last
```

Comment: This will break on commas inside individual field values.